# Laravel priority routing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to give a unique URL for each user on my database instead of `mysite.com/profile/1`, for example:

```
mysite.com/my-cool-user --> usersController@show
mysite.com/my-other-user --> userController@show
```

But if it fails (no such entery as `my-cool-user`) it will keep checking for the other routes.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will fail, instead you can use routing parameters.

```
Route::get('/{user-name}','userController@show');
```

Then in your controller method you add an argument to the method.

```
public function userController($userName){

// find the user by new username

User::where('username',$userName)->first();

}
```

{user-name} can be any username, if name matches in the database you will get the user profile.

In Laravel for routing the statement present at first in Routes.php will be processed first before the others which are below that particular statement. So if you have two same URL the first one will always be used.

Docs [Routing Parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: But if i'm putting that rule first, won't that make all the other rules that I have useless? for example I have a static route for /about page...

Comment: Got it! just placed the 'Route::get('/{username}','userController@show');' in the end of routes.php and it works ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Yes it will, it will look for about-page user from database if it exists it will get you a user if not it will fail. You can place this route below other routes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it to work it completely, but if you have only one route based on database, you could create such binding rule:

```
Route::bind('username', function ($value, $route) {
    return User::where('name', $value)->first();
});
```

and now create the following route **at the end of all routes**:

```
Route::get('/{username}', ['uses' => 'userController@show']);
```

and define your show function:

```
public function test($username  = null) {

    var_dump($username);
}
```

In above you could make redirection to main url if `$username` is null or display 404 page. However it still doesn't solve the issue when you have many routes based on database and all of them have the same pattern without any prefix.